# XML File with same elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a small problem (for me it's a big issue) in terms of reading an existing XML document. I have a file with a number of always identical elements. I need to create a list that clearly indicates which child belongs to which parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<componentTree name="Location">
  <componentRef ref="47350">
    <componentRef ref="47379">
      <componentRef ref="47425">
        <componentRef ref="47471" />
        <componentRef ref="47494" />
        <componentRef ref="47517">
          <componentRef ref="47632" />
          <componentRef ref="47655" />
          <componentRef ref="47678" />
        </componentRef>
      </componentRef>
    </componentRef>
    <componentRef ref="47402">
      <componentRef ref="47448">
        <componentRef ref="47540">
          <componentRef ref="47563">
            <componentRef ref="47586" />
            <componentRef ref="47609" />
          </componentRef>
        </componentRef>
      </componentRef>
    </componentRef>
  </componentRef>
</componentTree>
```

As an example for 47517
component 47517
parent: 47425
has children: yes

Does someone has a tip for me?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: And what class do you deserialize the XML into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like that with Linq to SQl

```
 XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var result = (from item in doc.Descendants("componentRef")
                         select new {Ref = (string)item.Attribute("ref"),  Parent = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("ref"), HasChild = item.FirstNode != null }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, fantastic... it is working. And it seems to be so easy. Thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem at all. Welcome to `Linq to Xml`!

Comment: BTW. You could mark this post as answered for noting that is useful and correct one.

Comment: Stackoverflow is completely new for me.... i have accepted it. thanks and kind regards... Bernd